# Getting bounding box of an HTML element excluding CSS transforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I realise this used to be the default behaviour of `getBoundingClientRect()` but it seems that I'm in the rare position of needing this feature!

I have a CSS animation that moves a div across the Y axis using `translate`. However, I want the finishing position of the div ...but before the animation has even begun.

Is there any (neat) way of doing this assuming I have no knowledge of the animation parameters?

Comment: clone the div, put it in it's final state, get position, delete the clone, should work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use getBoundingClientRect just as is.
Here is an example:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("move");
window.setInterval(function() {
  var structure = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  element.innerHTML = "left: " + Math.floor(structure.left) + "px<br/> top: " + Math.floor(structure.top) + "px";
}, 100);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 450px;
}
#move {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  animation: move 5s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: calc(100% - 200px);
    top: calc(100% - 200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="move">HELLO!</div>
```